# how to do aws iot jobs in python

Tags: python, aws-sdk, aws-iot

I have already created and deployed the job that controlled the connected iot devices using js(ref : [click here](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js#jobsAgent)).

Now i want to implement the job and want to control the connected iot devices using python.

If it is possible to implement the above task in python ?

I googled it but i didn't get any reference related to my query.Most of the time the search engine shows up the iot related jobs information.

Kindly comment the reference links that is useful for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to boto3, the python aws sdk:

- [IoT create_job()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iot.html#IoT.Client.create_job)
- [IoTJobsDataPlance](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iot-jobs-data.html)